# integral $\int \frac{1}{x\left(2+\sqrt[3]{\frac{x-1}{x}}\right)} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{1}{x\left(2+\sqrt[3]{\frac{x-1}{x}}\right)} dx$$
My answer is
$$ \textrm{let} \,u = \sqrt[3]{\frac{x-1}{x}} \Rightarrow   \frac{x-1}{x} = u^{3} $$ 
$$ \Rightarrow x = \frac{1}{1-u^{3}} \Rightarrow dx = \frac{3u^{2}}{(1-u^{3})^{2}}du $$
$$ \Rightarrow I = \int \frac{(1-u^{2})(3u^{2})}{(2+u)(1-u^{3})^{2}}du
 \Rightarrow I = 3\int \frac{u^{2}}{(2+u)(1-u^{3})}$$
I know that it can be solved by partial fraction by i don't like it ...
Is $u$-substitution not completely right or is there any easier method to solve it ..

Comment: The first $I=...$ step is wrong, but the second seems good, if you add a $dy$.

Comment: This is a fairly complicated-looking integral. Do you have any reason to think there's a substantially easier solution then the very straightforward one you've outlined?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: convert your Integrand into $$-1/3\, \left( u-1 \right) ^{-1}+{\frac {-u-1}{{u}^{2}+u+1}}+4/3\,
 \left( 2+u \right) ^{-1}
$$

Comment: This is literally the exact partial-fractions approach that OP was wondering about alternatives to.

Comment: i can't see really this approach

Comment: Again a seminal answer by Dr. Graubner

Comment: you Count my answers?

Comment: i just admire your genius, that's all...

Comment: +1: sometimes the partial fraction approach is the simplest way forward. At least it is conceptually clean; no blind guessing.

Comment: yes and Wolfram Alpha can not evaluate this integral and we can

Comment: ps. in the known elementary functions